# xcode ios split nsarray object into two separate objects

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xcode

hi im making mysql database where user can search for other users, when searching i want it to return user "id" and "name" since there could be users with the same name, so i include id. here is my .php

**EDIT**: since i didn't get answer i wanted, i thought i didn't make it clear enough, now i'm thinking in the other way to try it. Let's say **ID** will be in index 0 and **NAME**
in index 1, and so on.. see my php edit comment.

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `user` WHERE `name` LIKE '$search%'");


    mysql_close($con);

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($numrows!=0){
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)){

  $id = $row['id'];

  $name = $row['name'];

            echo ("$id,$name///");
```

Above on is my first attempt, note: edit is an example, what i'm thinking is make id, and name separate, then in Xcode separate them again to two different arrays lets say, all ID's will be in ID array by kinda jumping over one index every time "jumping over names", and NAMES in name array again jumping over ids.

```
    // EDIT: echo "%id///";
    // EDIT: echo "%name///";


  }

 }else{
   echo "fail";   
 }
```

and then in Xcode

```
     - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
   {
   if ([searchUsers.text length] != 0) {

   NSString *FindURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/search.php?search=%@",searchUsers.text];
    // to execute php code
    NSData  *URLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FindURL]];

    // to receive the returend value

    NSString *DataResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:URLData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSArray *FriendsArray = [DataResult componentsSeparatedByString:@"///"];



    userlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:FriendsArray];
    //[self searchDidSearch];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
   }

   }
```

The result is like "1,somename" "2,somename" and so on.  What i want is to split object so that **NAME** will be in the tableviewcell title, and **ID** in tableviewcell subtitle, and i want to apply that for each row.

Is there an easier way, or did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong, I think you just have one more step to go.
Loop through all the results and split the strings like this:

```
NSString * tempItem = [FriendsArray objectAtIndex:i]; //where i is each index, possibly in a loop
NSArray * splitObject = [tempItem componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now, splitObject's first object is the id and second object is the name. You can probably turn this into a loop and get what you need. There are many different ways to pass this data around, I'll leave that one to you.

Comment: Tried for loop stuff, still have no idea how to achieve what i want.. :(

Comment: Hey, just letting you know I let you on your own so you'd get that learning experience. Glad you had the tools to figure it out, thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make PHP output look something more like [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/)
Ex:

```
{      
  {
     "id" = 1;
     "name" = name1;
  },
   {
      "id" = 1;
      "name" = name2;
   },
}
```

And then you can access your values of "name" like this (by creating array of names using [fast enumeration](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/fast-enumeration-on-the-iphone.html) ):

```
    NSMutableArray *namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      for(NSDictionary *dict in dataArray) //dataArray NSArray of data from PHP output
      { 
          [result addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
      }
```

well and after that show names in tableViewCell subtitle with following code(in cellForRowAtIndexPath method):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectAtIndex:indexpathRow]];
```

It's not the best approach but i think it would be easier for you to work with array like this  in the future. Happy coding! :)

Comment: thanks for responding, not exactly what im looking for, anyways thanks!